# VBA - How to use LIKE Operator to look for two or more values

Tags: vba, excel

I have an condition statement where i'm looking for specific value using the *LIKE Operator* but it only returns one value, is it possible to return multiple value at the same time??

> If Sheet2.Cells(i, 8).Value Like "REPLACED MODEM*" Then

i want to find the two or more values in my cell, the values are *"REPLACED MODEM*"*, "*REPLACED DEFECTIVE MODEM* , "CHANGED MODEM"* i tried bunch of methods but no luck..

> If Sheet2.Cells(i, 8).Value Like "REPLACED MODEM*" or "*REPLACED
>   DEFECTIVE MODEM* or "CHANGED MODEM"* Then

i think the idea is like this(i already tried this not working...)

full code:

```
lastRowCri4 = Sheet2.Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRowCri4


            If Application.CountIfs(Sheet2.Columns(20), Sheet2.Cells(i, 20), _
                                          Sheet2.Columns(8), Sheet2.Cells(i, 8)) > 1 Then


               If Sheet2.Cells(i, 8).Value Like "REPLACED DEFECTIVE MODEM*" Or Cells(i, 8).Value Like "REPLACED MODEM" Then
                If Not CBool(Application.CountIfs(Sheet2.Columns(20), Sheet2.Cells(i, 20), _
                                                  Sheet2.Columns(8), Sheet2.Cells(i, 8), _
                                                  Sheet2.Columns(85), ">" & Sheet2.Cells(i, 85))) Then
                    Sheet2.Cells(i, 86).Resize(1, 2) = Array("1", "4")
                End If 'Columns(3) service number
            End If     'Columns(4) status

        End If 'Columns(4) date
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
If Cells(i,8).Value like "REPLACED*MODEM*" OR Cells(i,8).Value like "CHANGED MODEM*" Then
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "first value" ?

Comment: this "REPLACED*MODEM*